# Executing a block of code on site behind the scenes at regular time intervals

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET method that pulls user data from a database and creates login credentials for users for a web application I am building.

```
    var userDataList = new List<UserInfo>();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    try
    {
        //open SQL connection
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand getSumOfHours = new SqlCommand("SELECT LoginName, Email FROM [User] WHERE Deleted IS NULL", conn);
        //execute command and retrieve primary key from the above insert and assign to variable
        SqlDataReader reader = getSumOfHours.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            userDataList.Add(new UserInfo
            {
                userName = reader.GetString(0),
                email = reader.GetString(1)
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    foreach (var item in userDataList)
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.userName + " " + item.email);
        if (!(Roles.RoleExists("user")))
        {
            Roles.CreateRole("user");
        }
        if (Membership.GetUser(item.userName) == null)
        {
            Membership.CreateUser(item.userName, "password", item.email);
            Roles.AddUserToRole(item.userName, "user");
        }
    }
}
public class UserInfo
{
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

It works perfectly but currently I have it executing by pressing a button on a page. This is not ideal because someone has to remember to press the button for it to execute. Is it possible, while the site is live on the server, to have the site execute this block of code behind the scenes every few hours?

Comment: Set it up as a console application and set up a SQL Job or Windows Task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a web application for this.  Use something like a Windows Service or a Console Application that's scheduled to run at regular intervals.

Web applications are designed to be request/response systems.  They listen for requests (like pressing a button on the page) and actively respond to those requests.  Once that response is sent, the application is idle.

Furthermore, if the application is idle a lot, the host (the web server) can shut it down as part of managing its resources.  So you can't rely on a web application to be always *actively* running.  And even if you could, it would still need a request in order to do anything.

A Windows Service is always running in the background, and can use a `Timer` to perform a task at regular intervals.  Or a console application which performs the task can be scheduled to run at regular intervals.  (By the Windows Task Scheduler for example.)

Comment: Ok, will do. It's possible to interact with System.Web.Security and it's membership api in a console application?

Comment: @DavidTunnell: It's possible to load that namespace, but the context of a web application isn't there.  What do you need to do with that namespace?  The console application shouldn't be authenticating as a web user.

Comment: I'm using it to create user credentials for the web application

Comment: @DavidTunnell: It's definitely an uncommon use case.  Though it may be possible, as long as the assemblies are included and the configuration file contains what it would contain in the web application.  As a fallback I suppose you could have the console application manually insert the user data into the database, bypassing the membership objects which do it for you.

Comment: @David Isn't everything he needs to enter membership in [`System.Web.Security`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.aspx)?  As long as his console application can connect to the database, it shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: @jbaum012: Right, which is why it may be possible.  I can't think of a compelling reason why it wouldn't be, though I may be overlooking something.  It's just unusual is all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server, i.e. thru remote desktop, you can use the task secheduler to execute the code as often as you like.

If you don't have that kind of access, i.e. you are in a shared hosting setup, most of the big hosts (discountasp.net for example), offer the ability for you to schedule a page to be loaded on a certain schedule - that would be the easiest way to do it in that scenario.